# Images from url not loaded on mobile data connection

Tags: android, okhttp, android-glide, universal-image-loader

I am using Glide to load images from url onto an ImageView in a RecyclerView adapter. Everything works fine when a user is connected to the internet on wifi. However, when their connection is on mobile data, Glide throws an exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "http://......png" at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried using https but still the same issue persists.
Also tried almost all other image loading libraries including UniversalImageLoader, Fresco, Picasso but still the same error persists

Comment: can u show your glide code ?

Comment: are you sure this URL is available to you on mobile data?

Comment: try opening the URL on your browser first

Comment: try to hit that image URL with GET request, may be while you are loading the resource was not ready

Comment: Apparently when I try to load the url on a device browser its a 504 error but on a desktop browser it works.

Comment: GlideApp.with(context)
                                .load(url)
                                .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(circularProgressDrawable))
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                                .into(holder.mWallpaper);

Comment: `its a 504 error` means that it is not your problem. You can do nothing about it.

Comment: could be have an idea as to why the url loads the image successfully when i switch to wifi?, even on a device browser?

Comment: looks like using a bare IP adress instead of an equivalent domain name was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to put this line in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Probably WiFi is working globally on device, while mobile data is some sort of custom network state.
in [this tutorial (at FutureStud.io)](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-network-dependent-image-loading) use of Glide 4.x is shown. You can check connection from there and probably advance your debugging process, although the `uses-permission` snippet should work.

Answer (score -1):

Please use an async image loading and caching library similar to koush/ion
[Check this](https://github.com/koush/ion)

```
Ion.with(context)
.load("http://example.com/image.png")
.withBitmap()
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
.error(R.drawable.error_image)
.animateLoad(spinAnimation)
.animateIn(fadeInAnimation)
.intoImageView(imageView);
```

It's easy for you to implement and cache it too. remember to add neccersery manifest permissions. Hope you this helps!! Cheers

```
dependencies {
  implement 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}
```

add this to your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried it, url still won't work.

Comment: While this is nice clean code, this seems unrelated to the problem.